# Why does 'gem install bundler' throw "NoMethodError undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass"?

Tags: ruby, jruby, automated-tests

I tried the `gem update --system` command, but still I'm facing the same error while installing bundler.

```
C:\Users\swapnil\Desktop\testing\behavioral_tests\backlot>gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass
```

I went through this https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2372 issue but didn't get a proper solution.

I have a Win-7, 32 bit machine.

My gem environment is:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-05-16 patchlevel 392) [java]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: c:/jruby-1.7.4/bin/jruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: c:/jruby-1.7.4/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-java-1.7
  - GEM PATHS:
     - c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared
     - C:/Users/swapnil/.gem/jruby/1.9
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri --env-shebang"
     - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri --env-shebang"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: What's the full error trace? Add the output to the question.

Comment: Can you install any other gems?

Comment: yes I have installed jruby on my machine also i have facing this problem when I ran gem update --system command.

Comment: I Tried my self and figured out the problem behind this error is jruby. 

I have uninstalled jruby now 'gem install bundler' working fine but I need to use both ruby and jruby on win 7 platform. 

If anybody know, please add solution for installing ruby and jruby on win 7 platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Tried my self and figured out the problem behind this error is I haven't configured my Environment variable path *C:\jruby-1.7.4\bin* for jruby.

It is working fine for me now. Thanks to all for their efforts.

Comment: @Casper: Yes, I will accept it after 2 days as it is not allowing me to accept it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do following things:

1. Open command prompt after right click and run as Administrator.
2. Fire your command 'gem install bundler'.